# Run an external Python script on starting maya from a .bat file

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm attempting to run a python script that imports some assets into Maya when a .bat file is opened. The python script is not inside the Maya project. I've made a few attempts to run the file using a MEL script by calling it with:

`python("execfile('X:/SomeFolder/Test/PythonScript.py')")`

At start up I get the error:
// Error: python("execfile('X:/SomeFolder/Test/PythonScript.py')")eHalf; 
//
// Error: "D:\0_Scripts\3dsToMayaScripts\MELtoCallPython.mel" line 1.77: Syntax error //

However when I run the script from inside Maya it works without any issues.

edit: added the error and more details.

Comment: Is there any error occurred when it fails? Please share exact error statement.

Comment: Good call. I'm getting this error:
 // Error: python("execfile('X:/SomeFolder/Test/PythonScript.py')")eHalf;
I suspect it is because python isn't loaded on start so I need a way to delay the python call.
The same script runs with no errors when run from inside Maya

Comment: Have you set your PYTHONPATH environment variable? check after adding the same.

Comment: which python version you are using?

Comment: It's the embedded python version in Maya 2018. I was hoping to keep vanilla Maya so I can use the script elsewhere with less set up.

Comment: I have not set the PYTHONPATH. I was hoping to avoid altering any environment settings directly to avoid issues when I transfer the file to other computers.

Comment: I tried delaying the file startup by using evalDeferred in a MEL script.
global proc startLater()
{      python("execfile('D:/0_Scripts/3dsToMayaScripts/MaterialCreationScript.py')");
}
evalDeferred(startLater());
now the error is more specific, and I suspect you are correct that the solution is to modify the path:
# Error: file: D:\0_Scripts\3dsToMayaScripts\MELtoCallPython.mel line 3: RuntimeError: file D:/0_Scripts/3dsToMayaScripts/MaterialCreationScript.py line 7: Unrecognized file. # 

The only thing stopping me is that it does work once the program is running.